# The permission of the setuid helper is not correct

Tags: command-line, updates

I tried to open software & updates in Ubuntu 16.04 via terminal but I got this error message:

```
:~$ software-properties-gtk
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py:40: PyGIWarning: Gdk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gdk, Gtk, Gio, GLib
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py:40: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gdk, Gtk, Gio, GLib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 175, in activate_name_owner
    return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
    's', (bus_name,), **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties': no such name

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 101, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 141, in __init__
    proxy = bus.get_object("com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties", "/")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.PermissionsInvalid: The permission of the setuid helper is not correct
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt reinstall apt apt-utils aptdaemon aptdaemon-data update-manager update-manager-core dbus
```

https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2328602.html

The above worked for me.